# Nav::widget, добавить теги

Tags: yii2, виджет

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Yii2 Nav widget заключить содержимое `items => [[...]]` в тег `<p></p>`? А именно ссылку. Что бы на выходе получить вот это:

```
<li>
    <p class="navbar-btn" style="padding-left: 25px;">
       <a href="/competition/create" class="btn btn-default2">Создать батл</a>
    </p>
</li>
```

вместо этого:

```
<li>
    <a class="btn btn-default2" href="/competition/create">Создать батл</a>
</li>
```

Куда не пытался пристроить `Html::tag('p')`, ничего не получается.

```
<?php NavBar::begin([
        'renderInnerContainer'=>false,
        'brandLabel' => Html::img(['img/cldl-logo-black.png']),
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-sticky',
            'role' => 'navigation',
        ],

    ]); ?>
        <?php echo Nav::widget([
            'encodeLabels' => false,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
            ],
            'items' => [
                [

                    'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Создать батл'),
                    'url' => ['/competition/create'],
                    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default2'],

                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Категории'),
                    'url' => ['/site/categories'],
                    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default2'],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Регистрация'),
                    'url' => ['/user/sign-in/signup'],
                    'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
                    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default2'],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Войти'),
                    'url' => ['/user/sign-in/login'],
                    'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
                    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default2'],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Мой профиль'),
                    'url' => ['/user/default/index'],
                    'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
                    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default2'],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Админка'),
                    'url' => Yii::getAlias('@backendUrl'),
                    'visible' => Yii::$app->user->can('manager'),
                    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default2'],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Выйти (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')'),
                    'url' => ['/user/sign-in/logout'],
                    'linkOptions' => [
                        'data-method' => 'post',
                        'class' => 'btn btn-default2',
                    ],
                    'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest,
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'О проекте',
                    'url' => ['#'],
                    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default3'],
                ]
            ],
        ]); ?>
    <?php NavBar::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в виджете menu есть аттрибут 'submenuTemplate'
Может быть поможет и в вашем случае
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html#$submenuTemplate-detail

Comment: submenuTemplate это для выпадающего списка. Но ваша наводка мне помогла. Спасибо! Если использовать не Nav::widget a Menu::widget, то есть параметр 'template',   
`'template' => '<p class="navbar-btn" style="padding-left: 25px;"><a href="{url}" class="btn btn-default2">{label}</a></p>',`